# Scrapy-Splash not rendering this page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Could anybody please help understand why Splash wont render this page so I can scrape it.

url : https://www6.hertsmere.gov.uk/online-applications/weeklyListResults.do?action=firstPage

here is the spider i wrote:

```
class planningApplications(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'planning-application'

def start_requests(self):
    yield SplashRequest(
        url='https://www6.hertsmere.gov.uk/online- 
applications/weeklyListResults.do?action=firstPage',
        callback=self.parse
    )

def parse(self, response):
    self.log('I just visited: ' + response.url)
    self.log(response.body_as_unicode())
    item = {
        'test': response.xpath('//*[@id="searchresults"]/li[1]/a').extract_first()
    }
    yield item
```

Here is the Splash related settings that I have in my settings.py:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050/'

 DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
   'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 
810, 
}

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

Ive tried using scrapy shell using the line of code below and print out the response unicode but the html that holds the planning application is not there.

```
 scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www6.hertsmere.gov.uk/online-applications/pagedSearchResults.do?action=page&searchCriteria.page=2'
```

if the approach of using scrapy-splash wont work on the website would you recommend using selenium with scrapy?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I do new spider with your configs, and the problem is in `robots.txt`.

> DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: https://www6.hertsmere.gov.uk/online-applications/weeklyListResults.do?action=firstPage>

Crawl first need to downloads `robots.txt` before crawling. To change it you need to give `False` valut to [ROBOTSTXT_OBEY](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey).

Go to you `settings.py` and change it.

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Some **output** that i received.

```
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" cla$s="js"><head>

<!-- #BeginEditable "doctitle" -->
<title>
    Error
</title>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but this doesn't help get the data

Comment: do you run the `docker`?

Comment: can you show that you get back in terminal when you use `scrapy shell` ? and also can  you go to `localhost:8050` what do you see

Comment: im running it on linux virtual machine on aws but when i run the  scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www6.hertsmere.gov.uk/online-applications/pagedSearchResults.do?action=page&searchCriteria.page=2' i get just some of the html and not the div that holds the planning application details

Comment: and you can't get the errors from there? i need to look at errors, because in my case it works, there may be another problems

Comment: are you able to see for example '  Conversion of loft to habitable room with hip to gable roof alterations, rear dormer and 3 front rooflights. Certificate of Lawful Development (proposed).
77 Furzehill Road Borehamwood Hertfordshire WD6 2DL

Ref. No: 18/1443/CLP | Received: Thu 19 Jul 2018 | Validated: Thu 19 Jul 2018 | Status: Awaiting decision ' when you run the shell

Comment: try to use it on `local` machine, i see if it work local

Comment: also I dont get any errors I just dont see the div that holds the planning applications most of the html is missing compared to whats on the website when inspect it using chrome dev tools

Comment: but the `sheel` is opening ?

Comment: yes scrapy shell works fine its just when you run it on the url Ive stated above and you run the command print(response.body) the html printed out is less compared to whats on the actual website when you view it on the chrome dev tools so it not getting the renderd page after the javascript is run im assuming which i thought scrapy-splash was suppose to do